# get TempData Value in another Action

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0

I get the value from FormCollection and add in the **List**.Then the List will assigned to TempData.Now my question is ,How to get the TempData value in  **Redirect**  action and add send firstname and last name in Viewbag to view?How can I do this?

```
 public ActionResult show(FormCollection form)
        {
            string firstnamevalue = form["firstname"];
            string lastnamevalue = form["lastname"];

            List<string> list = new List<string>();
            list.Add(firstnamevalue);
            list.Add(lastnamevalue);


            TempData["Values"] = list;

            return RedirectToAction("Redirect");
        }

        public ActionResult Redirect()
        {
            //I need to get firstname and lastname here and add to view bag.

            return View();
        }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
public ActionResult show(FormCollection form)
        {
            string firstnamevalue = form["firstname"];
            string lastnamevalue = form["lastname"];

            List<string> list = new List<string>();
            list.Add(firstnamevalue);
            list.Add(lastnamevalue);


            TempData["Values"] = list;

            return RedirectToAction("Redirect");
        }

        public ActionResult Redirect()
        {
            //I need to get firstname and lastname here and add to view bag.
            List<string> lst=(List<string>)TempData["Values"]// cast tempdata to List of string
            ViewBag.Collection=lst;
            return View();
        }
```

In view you can access values as

```
<ul>

   <li>First Name: @ViewBag.Collection[0]</li>
   <li>Last Name: @ViewBag.Collection[1]</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how you store it on **viewbag** do it

```
      TempData["UsrName"] = LoginViewModel.LoginDataModel.UserName;
```

this can be stored in viewData like this

```
  public ActionResult LandingPage()
    {  
        ViewData["message"] = TempData["UsrName"].ToString();
        ViewData["person"] =Convert.ToInt32(TempData["UserTypeID"]);
        TempData.Keep();



   //and pass it as parameter like

        String PatID = Convert.ToString(ViewData["message"].ToString());
        int PersonType = Convert.ToInt32(ViewData["person"]);

    }





TempData.Keep()  - should be used to store the value till project stops running, otherwise  if user refreshes the page you will be losing the data on ViewData
```